# How to parse unstructured JSON file in Node?

Tags: json, node.js

I have to parse a JSON file that has many objects but no structure to the file. It looks like this:

```
{"obj1": "john"}
{"obj2": "sally"}
{"obj3": "veronica"}
```

Each object is on on it's own there is no container. So when I open the file and try to iterate through it I get the error `Unexpected token { in JSON`

Aside from wrapping the objects in an array and then manually going through the whole file to add commas, how can I parse this?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not json. so.... you can't parse it as if it were json. You could possibly iterate over the file, line by line, and then eval the objects, maybe

Comment: Yeah, it's not that it's an unstructured JSON file, it's its own format. JSON requires double quotes (not single quotes) around keys and strings, a single top-level thing, and commas between array entries and object properties.

Comment: Sorry, it is in double quotes. Just a habit working in singles

Comment: Ah, then just [iterate line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-node-js) and parse each one, adding it to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's really one-object-per-line, it's fairly straightforward to take the string, break it into lines, and `JSON.parse` each line:

```js
const str =
  '{"obj1": "john"}\n' +
  '{"obj2": "sally"}\n' +
  '{"obj3": "veronica"}';

const array = str.split(/[\r\n]+/)
                 .map(entry => JSON.parse(entry));

console.log(array);
```

...but that's assuming it really is one object per line.

If you're reading the file, you don't have to start out with all in one string as above; just [read line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-node-js) as [Kevin B points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42911485/how-to-parse-unstructured-json-file-in-node/42911657#comment72922370_42911485).

(Since you're using Node, I've happily used ES2015+ features above...)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you assume each line of the input file is complete, self-standing JSON, then a split-into-lines-then-parse-each strategy works well.

But even if the data isn't limited to a single line, not all is lost. You can heuristically parse the file. It isn't hyper-efficient, but except for very large files you'll probably never know the difference:

```
function incrementallyParseJSON(filepath) {
    var lines = fs.readFileSync(filepath)
                  .toString()
                  .split(/\n/g);
    var result = [];
    var [start, stop] = [0, 1];
    while (stop <= lines.length) {
        try { 
            var part = JSON.parse(lines.slice(start, stop).join('\n'));
            result.push(part);
            [start, stop] = [stop, stop+1]; 
        } catch (e) {
            stop += 1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

So if your file is:

```
{"obj1": "john"}
{"obj2": "sally",
 "more": "other"}
{"obj3": "veronica"}
"something"
12
```

The result will be:

```
[ { obj1: 'john' },
  { obj2: 'sally', more: 'other' },
  { obj3: 'veronica' },
  'something',
  12 ]
```

Example:

```js
function incrementallyParseJSON(str) {
    var lines = str.split(/\n/g);
    var result = [];
    var [start, stop] = [0, 1];
    while (stop <= lines.length) {
        try { 
            var part = JSON.parse(lines.slice(start, stop).join('\n'));
            result.push(part);
            [start, stop] = [stop, stop+1]; 
        } catch (e) {
            stop += 1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
var str =
  '{"obj1": "john"}\n' +
  '{"obj2": "sally",\n' +
  ' "more": "other"}\n' +
  '{"obj3": "veronica"}\n' +
  '"something"\n' +
  '12';

console.log(incrementallyParseJSON(str));
```