# How to upload a file to a javascript script

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, input, file-io

I'm writing a simple JS script which gets a file as input and does some manipulation to it:

```
node script.js file
```

The file part is accessed directly by using:

```
process.argv[2]
```

Now all i want is given that input, find that file and read it line by line into my function. I have a really hard time with this seemingly simple task since all solutions I found were HTML based.

I need this to run as an independent script.

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation of the `fs` module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a file one line at a time in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `fs` and `readline`:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream(/* Path to your file */),
  crlfDelay: Infinity
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
  console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
});
```

cf documentation for details, [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) & [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html)