# Unable to read a file line-by-line

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, stream

I'm trying to read a file line-by-line.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32599033/7400903), here is my code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require("readline");

const stream = fs.createReadStream("file.txt");
stream.on("error", err => console.log("Error: " + err));
const reader = readline.createInterface({input: stream});

reader.on("line", function (line) {
  console.log(line);
});
```

However, nothing is printed.

Here is the contents of the `reader` object:

```
Interface {
  _sawReturnAt: 0,
  isCompletionEnabled: true,
  _sawKeyPress: false,
  _previousKey: null,
  domain: null,
  _events:
   { close: { [Function: bound onceWrapper] listener: [Function: onSelfCloseWithoutTerminal] } },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  output: undefined,
  input:
   ReadStream {
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 65536,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: false,
        sync: true,
        needReadable: false,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: true,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: { end: [Array], error: [Function], data: [Function: ondata] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     path: 'file.txt',
     fd: null,
     flags: 'r',
     mode: 438,
     start: undefined,
     end: Infinity,
     autoClose: true,
     pos: undefined,
     bytesRead: 0 },
  historySize: 30,
  removeHistoryDuplicates: false,
  crlfDelay: 100,
  _prompt: '> ',
  terminal: false,
  _decoder:
   StringDecoder {
     encoding: 'utf8',
     fillLast: [Function: utf8FillLast],
     lastNeed: 0,
     lastTotal: 0,
     lastChar: <Buffer 2d 00 00 00> } }
```

What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: what version of node are you using?  according to the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline) node 10 comes with a builtin `readline` module

Comment: Which readline module are you using?

Comment: Your code works for me out of the box in Node v.9.