# I want store web log that using morgan and express to json file

Tags: json, node.js, express, morgan

I want store JSON file each like form

```
[
 {
   "remote-addr" : "127.0.0.1",
   "date"  : " 2018.07.28"
 }
]
```

and i use this code

```
var format=json(
    ':remote-addr:date'
);

app.use(logger({
    format:format,
    stream: fs.createWriteStream('log.json')
}));
```

i use this code and get

```
{"remote-addr":"::ffff:127.0.0.1","date":"Sat, 28 Jul 2018 04:38:41 GMT"}
{"remote-addr":"::ffff:127.0.0.1","date":"Sat, 28 Jul 2018 04:38:41 GMT"}
{"remote-addr":"::ffff:127.0.0.1","date":"Sat, 28 Jul 2018 04:38:42 GMT"}
{"remote-addr":"::ffff:127.0.0.1","date":"Sat, 28 Jul 2018 04:38:48 GMT"}
```

this is json file but there no [ ] and ,

how to get json file??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically Morgan does not allow you to do this, because it's entire purpose is to write **one standard `access.log` line per request** (credits to [Douglas Wilson](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/issues/65#issuecomment-107121741) for pointing that out).

Yes, you can hack around the single log line, like you did, which makes it a valid JSON line. However, in order to make your `log.json` file to be a valid JSON as well, the only way I can think of is to implement some kind of post-processing to the file.

Here's how the post-processing will look like: First, you need to read [line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32599033/1333836) the file. Then, create your valid JSON. Finally - save it in a separate file (or override the log.json anyways).

Here's how I did it. Input: your current `log.json` file:

```
{"remote-addr":"::ffff:127.0.0.1","date":"Sat, 28 Jul 2018 04:38:41 GMT"}
{"remote-addr":"::ffff:127.0.0.1","date":"Sat, 28 Jul 2018 04:38:41 GMT"}
{"remote-addr":"::ffff:127.0.0.1","date":"Sat, 28 Jul 2018 04:38:42 GMT"}
{"remote-addr":"::ffff:127.0.0.1","date":"Sat, 28 Jul 2018 04:38:48 GMT"}
```

The post-processing script I wrote:

```
const fs = require('fs');
//  Since Node.js v0.12 and as of Node.js v4.0.0, there is a stable
// readline core module. That's the easiest way to read lines from a file,
// without any external modules. Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32599033/1333836
const readline = require('readline');

const lineReader = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('log.json')
});

const realJSON = [];
lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    realJSON.push(JSON.parse(line));
});

lineReader.on('close', function () {
    // final-log.json is the post-processed, valid JSON file
    fs.writeFile('final-log.json', JSON.stringify(realJSON), 'utf8', () => {
        console.log('Done!');
    });
});
```

Result: the `final-log.json` file, which is a **valid JSON** (I validated it with [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/), all good).

```
[{
    "remote-addr": "::ffff:127.0.0.1",
    "date": "Sat, 28 Jul 2018 04:38:41 GMT"
}, {
    "remote-addr": "::ffff:127.0.0.1",
    "date": "Sat, 28 Jul 2018 04:38:41 GMT"
}, {
    "remote-addr": "::ffff:127.0.0.1",
    "date": "Sat, 28 Jul 2018 04:38:42 GMT"
}, {
    "remote-addr": "::ffff:127.0.0.1",
    "date": "Sat, 28 Jul 2018 04:38:48 GMT"
}]
```