# How to implement the Unix "paste" command in Node.js without loading whole files into memory?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The basic [Unix paste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_(Unix)) can be implemented in Python like (the example works with two files only; Unix paste works with multiple files):

```py
def paste(fn1, fn2):
  with open(fn1) as f1:
    with open(fn2) as f2:
      for l1 in f1:
        l2 = f2.readline()
        if l2 != None:
          print(l1[:-1] + "\t" + l2[:-1])
        else:
          print(l1[:-1])
      for l2 in f2:
        print("\t" + l2[:-1])

import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
  if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
    paste(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

The task is to implement the same functionality in Node.js. **Importantly**, as the input file can be huge, the implementation should read the input file line by line, not reading the entire file into the memory. I want to see how to achieve this with built-in Node functionality without external packages.

Note that it is easy to implement Unix paste with synchronous I/O as is shown in the Python example, but Node doesn't provide synchronous I/O for line reading. Meanwhile, there are [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-node-js) to read one file by line with asynchronous I/O, but jointly reading two files is harder because the two streams are not synchronized.

So far the only solution I can think of is to implement synchronous line reading using the basic [read](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlereadbuffer-offset-length-position) API. Dave Newton pointed out in the comment that the npm [n-readlines package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n-readlines) implements this approach in 100+ lines. Because n-readlines inspects each byte to find line endings, I suspect it is inefficient and thus did a [microbenchmark](https://github.com/attractivechaos/line-by-line) with results shown in the table below. For line reading (not for this task), n-readlines is 3 times as slow as a [Node Readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) implementation and is an order of magnitude slower than built-in line reading in Python, Perl or mawk.

What is the proper way to implement Unix paste? N-readlines is using synchronous APIs. Would a good async solution be cleaner and faster?

| Language | Runtime | Version | Elapsed (s) | User (s) | Sys (s) | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JavaScript | node | 21.5.0 | 6.30 | 5.33 | 0.90 | [lc-node.js](https://github.com/attractivechaos/line-by-line/blob/main/lc-node.js) |
|  | node | 21.5.0 | 22.34 | 20.41 | 2.24 | [lc-n-readlines.js](https://github.com/attractivechaos/line-by-line/blob/main/lc-n-readlines.js) |
|  | bun | 1.0.20 | 4.91 | 5.30 | 1.47 | [lc-node.js](https://github.com/attractivechaos/line-by-line/blob/main/lc-node.js) |
|  | bun | 1.0.20 | 21.16 | 19.22 | 3.37 | [lc-n-readlines.js](https://github.com/attractivechaos/line-by-line/blob/main/lc-n-readlines.js) |
|  | k8 | 1.0 | 1.49 | 1.06 | 0.37 | [lc-k8.js](https://github.com/attractivechaos/line-by-line/blob/main/lc-k8.js) |
| C | clang | 15.0.0 | 0.71 | 0.35 | 0.35 | [lc-c.c](https://github.com/attractivechaos/line-by-line/blob/main/lc-c.c) |
| python | python | 3.11.17 | 3.48 | 2.85 | 0.62 | [lc-python.py](https://github.com/attractivechaos/line-by-line/blob/main/lc-python.py) |
| perl | perl | 5.34.3 | 1.70 | 1.13 | 0.57 | [lc-perl.pl](https://github.com/attractivechaos/line-by-line/blob/main/lc-perl.pl) |
| awk | mawk | 1.3.4 | 2.08 | 1.27 | 0.80 | [lc-awk.awk](https://github.com/attractivechaos/line-by-line/blob/main/lc-awk.awk) |
|  | apple awk | ? | 90.06 | 87.90 | 1.12 | [lc-awk.awk](https://github.com/attractivechaos/line-by-line/blob/main/lc-awk.awk) |

Comment: What "UNIX paste" command are we talking about here? *edit* oh, wow, and here I've been using UNIX since about 1982 and I never used it.

Comment: Why not try a NodeJS file IO tutorial or look at the fs docs then?

Comment: … which is why there’s tutorials/docs (and dupes of the same question on SO), I guess.

Comment: The implementation of node-readlines is <200 lines and does roughly what you’d expect, maybe looking at other peoples’ solutions would be helpful. Whether it’s one file or two the process is the same: read bytes, find lines, repeat until eof.

Comment: @DaveNewton See edit. Which "node-readlines" are you talking about? The npm [readlines package](https://github.com/booxood/readlines/blob/master/lib/readlines.js) seems to be reading the whole file [internally](https://github.com/booxood/readlines/blob/7b390e3685af5b80cb66e2812abf6bc3204cc849/lib/readlines.js#L19). Anyway, if you think this is trivial, an answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: It might be better to make an attempt and ask specific questions based on the attempt(s), which is more what SO is for. I misnamed the library, sorry—it’s n-readlines. It’s an implementation that may make more sense to you at this point as opposed to maybe-more-node-y streams.

Comment: Tangential: I didn’t say it was “trivial”, it may not be if one isn’t familiar with async in general. But this is one of those problems that’d be good to try tackling (IMO).

Comment: @DaveNewton "n-readlines" does what I said in the edit. It should work. Thanks for the pointer. But you need 100+ lines and as I said, checking each byte will be slow. In addition, n-realines is using synchronous APIs. Is it possible to use async to implement the task? I have no clue and can't be more specific.

Comment: Sure, it can be done without using sync—same general process. You may be over-thinking this—I **really** recommend spending some time with async and/or NodeJS fs tutorials, I think it will help quite a bit.

Comment: @Pointy me either, and although you've got me more than beat I booted up my first Linux distro in '97... time to do some searching to see what else I've been missing all these years.

Comment: If you use [filehandle.readLines](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlereadlinesoptions) it's indeed trivial (if you know how to iterate asyncIterables manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { open as fsOpenAsync } from 'node:fs/promises'
import { createWriteStream } from 'node:fs'

const filenames = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']
const outname = 'out.txt'

await paste(filenames, outname)

/**
 * Read multiple files line by line and write lines concatenated by `\t`
 */
async function paste(from: string[], to: string) {
  const files = await Promise.all(filenames.map(fn => fsOpenAsync(fn)))
  const zip = zipAsyncs(files.map(f => f.readLines()[Symbol.asyncIterator]()))
  const writeStream = createWriteStream(to, { flags: 'w' })
  for await (const lines of zip)
    writeStream.write(`${lines.map(e => e ?? '').join('\t')}\n`)
  writeStream.close()
  await Promise.all(files.map(f => f.close()))
}

/**
 * Zip multiple async iterables, returning `undefined` for missing values
 * @template {T}
 * @param {AsyncIterator<T>[]} its
 * @returns {AsyncGenerator<IteratorResult<T | undefined, any>[]>}
 */
async function* zipAsyncs(its) {
  while (true) {
    const results = await Promise.all(its.map(e => e.next()))
    yield results.map(r => r.value)
    if (results.every(r => r.done))
      return
  }
}
```

Comment: @user172818 please ping me, I wonder how well would this benchmark

Comment: Thank you so much. See timing [here](https://github.com/attractivechaos/line-by-line?tab=readme-ov-file#elapsed-time-for-pasting-two-files). Yours is twice as fast as the version I got and it is much shorter. I am accepting your answer. filehandle.readLines() is somewhat new (in v18.11.0). I missed it.

Comment: This is a good approach, but beware of using the [async iterator](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#rlsymbolasynciterator) of the [readline interface stream](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#class-interfaceconstructor) returned by [`readLines()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlereadlinesoptions): "*`readline.createInterface()` will start to consume the input stream once invoked. Having asynchronous operations between interface creation and asynchronous iteration may result in missed lines.*" I think the code in this answer doesn't have this problem, but it's easy to trip.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an answer based on [n-readlines](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n-readlines). It is lengthy and inefficient (see the table in the question) but it solves the problem. I am still looking for a better solution.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

// the following implementation is copied from https://github.com/nacholibre/node-readlines (the n-readlines package)
// Written by Liucw and distributed under the MIT license
class LineByLine {
    constructor(file, options) {
        options = options || {};
        if (!options.readChunk) options.readChunk = 1024;
        if (!options.newLineCharacter) {
            options.newLineCharacter = 0x0a; //linux line ending
        } else {
            options.newLineCharacter = options.newLineCharacter.charCodeAt(0);
        }
        if (typeof file === 'number') {
            this.fd = file;
        } else {
            this.fd = fs.openSync(file, 'r');
        }
        this.options = options;
        this.newLineCharacter = options.newLineCharacter;
        this.reset();
    }
    _searchInBuffer(buffer, hexNeedle) {
        let found = -1;
        for (let i = 0; i <= buffer.length; i++) {
            let b_byte = buffer[i];
            if (b_byte === hexNeedle) {
                found = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
    reset() {
        this.eofReached = false;
        this.linesCache = [];
        this.fdPosition = 0;
    }
    close() {
        fs.closeSync(this.fd);
        this.fd = null;
    }
    _extractLines(buffer) {
        let line;
        const lines = [];
        let bufferPosition = 0;
        let lastNewLineBufferPosition = 0;
        while (true) {
            let bufferPositionValue = buffer[bufferPosition++];
            if (bufferPositionValue === this.newLineCharacter) {
                line = buffer.slice(lastNewLineBufferPosition, bufferPosition);
                lines.push(line);
                lastNewLineBufferPosition = bufferPosition;
            } else if (bufferPositionValue === undefined) {
                break;
            }
        }
        let leftovers = buffer.slice(lastNewLineBufferPosition, bufferPosition);
        if (leftovers.length) {
            lines.push(leftovers);
        }
        return lines;
    };
    _readChunk(lineLeftovers) {
        let totalBytesRead = 0;
        let bytesRead;
        const buffers = [];
        do {
            const readBuffer = new Buffer(this.options.readChunk);
            bytesRead = fs.readSync(this.fd, readBuffer, 0, this.options.readChunk, this.fdPosition);
            totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead + bytesRead;
            this.fdPosition = this.fdPosition + bytesRead;
            buffers.push(readBuffer);
        } while (bytesRead && this._searchInBuffer(buffers[buffers.length-1], this.options.newLineCharacter) === -1);
        let bufferData = Buffer.concat(buffers);
        if (bytesRead < this.options.readChunk) {
            this.eofReached = true;
            bufferData = bufferData.slice(0, totalBytesRead);
        }
        if (totalBytesRead) {
            this.linesCache = this._extractLines(bufferData);
            if (lineLeftovers) {
                this.linesCache[0] = Buffer.concat([lineLeftovers, this.linesCache[0]]);
            }
        }
        return totalBytesRead;
    }
    next() {
        if (!this.fd) return false;
        let line = false;
        if (this.eofReached && this.linesCache.length === 0) {
            return line;
        }
        let bytesRead;
        if (!this.linesCache.length) {
            bytesRead = this._readChunk();
        }
        if (this.linesCache.length) {
            line = this.linesCache.shift();
            const lastLineCharacter = line[line.length-1];
            if (lastLineCharacter !== this.newLineCharacter) {
                bytesRead = this._readChunk(line);
                if (bytesRead) {
                    line = this.linesCache.shift();
                }
            }
        }
        if (this.eofReached && this.linesCache.length === 0) {
            this.close();
        }
        if (line && line[line.length-1] === this.newLineCharacter) {
            line = line.slice(0, line.length-1);
        }
        return line;
    }
}

function main(args) {
    if (args.length < 2) {
        console.log("Usage: node lc-n-readlines.js <in1.txt> <in2.txt>");
        return;
    }
    const f1 = new LineByLine(args[0]);
    const f2 = new LineByLine(args[1]);
    let l1, l2;
    while (l1 = f1.next()) {
        if (l2 = f2.next()) {
            console.log(`${l1}\t${l2}`);
        } else {
            console.log(l1);
        }
    }
    while (l2 = f2.next())
        console.log(`\t${l2}`);
}

main(process.argv.splice(2));
```