# How can I correctly show a Chinese string from calling raw_input() in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I was trying to conquer the Chinese encoding issue. So far the only obstacle before me is to show correctly the user typed in the `raw_input()`. For example, my abstract solution about this part is like this:

```
#coding: utf-8
name_a = raw_input('请输入文字')
print name_a
```

But by this I can only show '请输入文字' correctly. If a user typed in a Chinese character in raw_input(), the print name_a will show utf-8 code point like '/xb7'

Anyhow, I've searched online, and find this code can solve my problem:

```
#coding: utf-8

n=raw_input(unicode('请输入文字','utf-8').encode('gbk'))
print n
```

It worked! But when I trying to plant it into my own code. My code can't be executed. And there was something even more weird happened. Later when I copy this code into other empty file, it can't work, too. Just a blink and the program was over (I know the feature of python under Windows environment so I added `x = input()` at the end of the file). And later I deleted the original test py file which contains the second code paragraph. Now I can't execute it in any new created file now.

I'm using Python 2.7 under Windows XP environment

What happened?

And is there another way that can help me show the Chinese content the user typed into the `raw_input()`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: Perhaps relevant, since this looks like this might be a Windows issue? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4942305/646543

Comment: @Mario did any of the answer answer your question?

Comment: @alvas, I get some useful ideas here, and my problem was solved in an concidental way, which I realized I should use %s instead of %r in my code, and then I can get Chinese symbols. By the way, I didn't type my whole code here in this question.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
x = raw_input(u'请输入文字'.encode("utf8"))
```

Also, I was successfully able to just `print(x)` and have it show the Chinese characters, so it's likely an OS (or terminal client) font rendering issue you are having.

Side note: NEVER use `input()` in Python 2.x. It implicitly `eval`s all data the user enters (`input()` == `eval(raw_input())`), so something like `__import__("os").system("rm -rf /*")` would wipe the hard drive of the computer running the Python script.

Comment: I just tried testing this, and it didn't work for me. Command prompt displays "Φ»╖Φ╛ôσàÑµûçσ¡ù". Which OS are you using?

Comment: i'm confused. how did `input()` related to the crazy `rm -rf` from `os.system`??

Comment: @alvas Since in Python 2.x `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`, any user input is evaluated as Python code. So if for example this script were running on a server and the user entered that code, your server's hard drive would be wiped. I like to always write and encourage secure coding habits.

Comment: @Michael0x2a Works on OS X and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Using this code:

```
#coding: utf-8

x = raw_input(u'请输入文字: '.encode("utf8"))
print "reprinting:",x
```

[out]:

```
$ python test.py
请输入文字: 123
reprinting: 123
```

So possibly it's not a python issue but an issue on your OS. If you get jumbled up outputs on the console, maybe it's font.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#coding: utf-8
import sys

name_a = raw_input('请输入文字：'.encode(sys.stdout.encoding))
print name_a.decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
print name_a
```

Sample output:

```
请输入文字：中文字符
中文字符
中文字符
```

Comment: I tested this on python, but it shows UnicodeDEcodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 0:ordinal no in range(128)       I was using python2.7 on Ubuntu at the moment

Comment: above code works when Python's sys default encoding is utf-8.
add following two lines after import sys, it shpuld works.
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

Answer (score 0):

My script main.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
reload(sys) 
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

name = raw_input("中文名字: ".encode(sys.stdout.encoding)) 
print name
```

or

```
name = raw_input("中文名字: ".encode(sys.stdin.encoding))
```

I invoke it use window pshell and (python 2.7.8)

```
python mian.py
```

then can display correctly:

```
中文名字: 中文名字测试
中文名字测试
```

May it helps someone.

Comment: Do not cargo-cult the `sys.setdefaultencoding()` trick please. There is no need to clobber the standard system codec, and this can break code that actually relies on non-ASCII data throwing an exception when implicitly decoded or encoded.

Comment: Thanks for your comments very much. I will nerve do it again, I am a newcomer.