# How do I write a file whose *filename* contains utf8 characters in Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, utf-8, filenames, cmd

I am struggling creating a file that contains non-ascii characters.

The following script works fine, if it is called with `0` as parameter but dies when called with `1`.

The error message is *open: Invalid argument at C:\temp\filename.pl line 15.*

The script is started within `cmd.exe`.

I expect it to write a file whose name is either (depending on the paramter) `äöü.txt` or `äöü☺.txt`. But I fail to create the filename containing a smiley.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Encode 'encode';

#   Text is stored in utf8 within *this* file.
use utf8;

my $with_smiley = $ARGV[0];

my $filename = 'äöü' . 
  ($with_smiley ? '☺' : '' ).
   '.txt';

open (my $fh, '>', encode('cp1252', $filename)) or die "open: $!";

print $fh "Filename: $filename\n";

close $fh;
```

I am probably missing something that is obvious to others, but I can't find, so I'd appreciate any pointer towards solving this.

Comment: What error message do you get if you let open die?

Comment: @mugen: I have changed the script to let it die and added the error message.

Comment: What's with the cp1252? Does that code page contain this character? You are definitely not creating an UTF8 filename here!

Comment: What is the reason for needing a file name with Unicode characters in it? Perhaps you can work around that instead.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796127/what-is-the-universal-way-to-use-file-i-o-api-with-unicode-filenames

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, saying "UTF-8 character" is weird. UTF-8 can encode any Unicode character, so the UTF-8 character set is the Unicode character set. That means you want to create file whose name contain Unicode characters, and more specifically, Unicode characters that aren't in cp1252.

I've [answered](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=912449) this on PerlMonks in the past. Answer copied below.

---

Perl treats file names as opaque strings of bytes. That means that file names need to be encoded as per your "locale"'s encoding (ANSI code page).

In Windows, code page `1252` is commonly used, and thus the encoding is usually [`cp1252`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp1252).* However, `cp1252` doesn't support Tamil and Hindi characters [or "☺"].

Windows also provides a "Unicode" aka "Wide" interface, but Perl doesn't provide access to it using builtins**. You can use [Win32API::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32API::File)'s `CreateFileW`, though. IIRC, you need to still need to encode the file name yourself. If so, you'd use `UTF-16le` as the encoding.

Aforementioned [Win32::Unicode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::Unicode) appears to handle some of the dirty work of using [Win32API::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32API::File) for you. I'd also recommend starting with that.

* — The code page is returned (as a number) by the `GetACP` system call. Prepend "`cp`" to get the encoding.

** — Perl's support for Windows sucks in some respects.

Comment: That is fully equivalent to “Windows’s support for POSIX filenames sucks in some respects.”

Comment: @ikegami, Widows does purport to be POSIX compliant in some areas, notably file system, and file naming. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976809.aspx

Comment: @tchrist, Even if it's true (and Ven'Tatsu seems to claim otherwise), that has nothing to do with the topic at hand. Perl claims to support Windows, but it doesn't in this area.

Comment: @ikegami, I'd argue that the reality lies between Perl not supporting Widows, and Windows not supporting POSIX. Some of the POSIX on Windows features are only available if the executable has the compiled for the POSIX subsystem flag set. Unfortunately this flag also changes other behaviors that would violate the principal of least surprise for a Windows developer.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu, If you tried to create a file named "☺" on a POSIX system that used the iso-8859-1 locale, you would have the same problem. This has absolutely nothing to do with POSIX, and all with Perl using an obsolete interface isntead of using CreateFileW. tchrist is engaging in baseless MS bashing.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu, Even if it had something to do with POSIX, any compliance or lack of compliance to standards on Windows's behalf does NOT excuse Perl's lack of support for Windows in this area.

Answer (score 1):

The following runs on Windows 7, ActiveState Perl. It writes "hello there" to a file with hebrew characters in its name:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Unicode file names on Windows using Perl
# Philip R Brenan at gmail dot com, Appa Apps Ltd, 2013
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

use feature ":5.16";
use Data::Dump qw(dump);
use Encode qw/encode decode/;
use Win32API::File qw(:ALL);

# Create a file with a unicode name

my $e  = "\x{05E7}\x{05EA}\x{05E7}\x{05D5}\x{05D5}\x{05D4}".
         "\x{002E}\x{0064}\x{0061}\x{0074}\x{0061}"; # File name in UTF-8
my $f  = encode("UTF-16LE", $e);  # Format supported by NTFS
my $g  = eval dump($f);           # Remove UTF ness
   $g .= chr(0).chr(0);           # 0 terminate string
my $F  = Win32API::File::CreateFileW
 ($g, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, [], OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, 0); #  Create file via Win32API
say $^E if $^E;                   # Write any error message

# Write to the file

OsFHandleOpen(FILE, $F, "w") or die "Cannot open file";
binmode FILE;                      
print FILE "hello there\n";      
close(FILE);
```

Comment: I think you used `my $g  = eval dump($f);` to downgrade the scalar? If so, it would be far better to use `utf8::downgrade( my  $g = $f );`, but there's no reason to downgrade since `encode` always produces a downgraded scalar.

Answer (score -1):

no need to encode the filename (at least not on linux). This code works on my linux system:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

#   Text is stored in utf8 within *this* file.
use utf8;

my $with_smiley = $ARGV[0] || 0;

my $filename = 'äöü' .
  ($with_smiley ? '?' : '' ).
     '.txt';

open my $fh, '>', $filename or die "open: $!";

binmode $fh, ':utf8';

print $fh "Filename: $filename\n";

close $fh;
```

HTH, Paul

Comment: If I don't encode() the filename (and pass parameter 0), the filesnames will look like `Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼.txt`.

Comment: The smiley character is actually `v63`, not `?`.

Comment: That's utf8 alright; if you are not using a utf8-capable system, it will display the name wrong, but the name is correct.

Comment: @trip I see a `?` in pavel's code, and `☺` (smiley) in René's.

Comment: i guess tripleee referred to Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼.txt.. hehe, questions like this HAVE to end up in character mess :P