# Copy/rename images with utf8 names using csv file

Tags: perl, csv, utf-8

I'm working on a script to batch rename and copy images based on a csv file. The csv consists of column 1: old name and column 2: new name. I want to use the csv file as input for the perl script so that it checks the old name and makes a copy using the new name into a new folder. The problem that (i think) I'm having has to do with the images. They contain utf8 characters like ß etc. When I run the script it prints out this: Barfu├ƒg├ñsschen where it should be Barfußgässchen and the following error:

```
Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline at C:/Perl64/lib/File/Copy.pm line 148, <$INFILE> line 1.
Copy failed: No such file or directory at X:\Script directory\correction.pl line 26, <$INFILE> line 1.
```

I know it has to do with Binmode utf8 but even when i try a simple script (saw it here: [How can I output UTF-8 from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627661/how-can-i-output-utf-8-from-perl)):

```
use strict;
use utf8;
my $str = 'Çirçös';
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
print "$str\n";
```

it prints out this: Ãirþ÷s

This is my entire script, can someone explain to me where i'm going wrong? (its not the cleanest of codes because i was testing out stuff).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;
use utf8;

my $inputfile  = shift || die "give input!\n";
#my $outputfile = shift || die "Give output!\n";

open my $INFILE,  '<', $inputfile   or die "In use / not found :$!\n";
#open my $OUTFILE, '>', $outputfile  or die "In use / not found :$!\n";

binmode($INFILE, ":encoding(utf8)");

#binmode($OUTFILE, ":encoding(utf8)");

while (<$INFILE>) {
s/"//g;
my @elements = split /;/, $_;

my $old = $elements[1];
my $new = "new/$elements[3]";
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
print "$old | $new\n";

copy("$old","$new") or die "Copy failed: $!";
#copy("Copy.pm",\*STDOUT);

#   my $output_line = join(";", @elements);
#    print $OUTFILE $output_line;
#print "\n"
}

close $INFILE;
#close $OUTFILE;

exit 0;
```

Comment: About your first snippet: Is the .pl file itself encoded in utf8? The `use utf8` pragma tells Perl that your sourcecode is written in utf8. It doesn't concern the data.

Comment: Where are you printing the output to? A Linux shell? Also, how are you creating the file?

Comment: I can confirm that your first snippet works fine on my Linux shell with the LANG set to `en_GB.UTF-8` and Putty set to UTF-8. I created the file using VIM in the same shell.

Comment: @Fuzzyfelt I'm on a windows system if that's what u mean. I created the csv file manually. Did a dir command on the directory and opened it in excel. I alse created the new names in the same file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure every step of the process is using UTF-8.

When you create the input CSV, you need to make sure that it's saved as UTF-8, preferably without a BOM. Windows Notepad will add a BOM so try Notepad++ instead which gives you more control of the encoding.

You also have the problem that the Windows console is not UTF-8 compliant by default. See [Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how). Either set the codepage with `chcp 65001` or don't change the STDOUT encoding.

In terms of your code, the first error regarding the new line is probably due to the trailing new line from the CSV. Add `chomp()` after `while (<$INFILE>) {`

Update:

To "address" the file you need to encode your filenames in the correct locale - See [How do you create unicode file names in Windows using Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992460/how-do-you-create-unicode-file-names-in-windows-using-perl) and [What is the universal way to use file I/O API with unicode filenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796127/what-is-the-universal-way-to-use-file-i-o-api-with-unicode-filenames). Assuming you're using Western 1252 / Latin, this means when your copy command will look like:

```
copy(encode("cp1252", $old), encode("cp1252", $new))
```

Also, your open should also encode the filename:

```
open my $INFILE,  '<', encode("cp1252", $inputfile)
```

Update 2:

As you're running in a DOS window, remove `binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");` and leave the default codepage in place.

Comment: I created the CSV in notepad++ as utf8 without a BOM so that shouldn't be it. I'm checking the other 2 suggestions u gave me right now.

Comment: Adding `chomp;` after `while (<$INFILE>) {` did the trick for the first error. Setting the codepage first and then trying the script once more does not change anything. I still get the message copy failed. I print the old and new name and you can see that the old name is incorrect and thats why it does not match the actual file and fails