# Could Not Find Path Specified: CreateDirectoryW

Tags: c, winapi, path, nested, prefix

VS2015, Unicode: Getting the "Could Not Find the Path Specified" error running the following code in a listbox:

```
wchar_t *currPath, *cumPath;
int listTotal = 5;
int pathLength = 32760;
listTotal = SendMessageW(hList, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0);
wcscpy_s(cumPath, pathLength, L"\\\\?\\C:\\");
//wcscpy_s(cumPath, pathLength, L"C:\\"); //Tried this, no difference
wcscpy_s(currPath, MAX_PATH - 3, L"");
for (int i = 0; i < listTotal; i++) {
    SendMessageW(hList, LB_GETTEXT, i, (LPARAM) currPath); //"My Nested Path" picked up from textbox OK
    wcscat_s(cumPath, pathLength, (wchar_t *) currPath);
    \\OK but doubled backslashes
    wcscat_s(cumPath, MAX_PATH - 3, __TEXT("\\"));
    \\appear in debugger variable contents
}
int errorcode = CreateDirectoryW(cumPath, NULL);
if (errorcode == 0) {
    ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateDirectoryW"));
    //GetLastError courtesy [MSDN][1]

}
```

*Meh*, have I missed something fundamental here?
 The double backslash is not parsed out of the variable name. Is there a way to construct a macro using a verbatim or "as is" prefix that works in conjunction with TEXT or L?

**Edit1** The following two lines preceded the code:

```
currPath = (wchar_t *)calloc(pathLength, sizeof(wchar_t));
cumPath = (wchar_t *)calloc(pathLength, sizeof(wchar_t));
```

Both these vars are declared module wide. *However*, prior to entry on this sub there was:

```
 currPath = (wchar_t *)calloc(pathLength, sizeof(wchar_t));
 ...
 free(currPath);
```

Would the "re-calloc" of currPath have upset anything?

**Edit2**: No, tried with another variable. The value of cumPath before CreateDirectoryW is as expected?

> cumPath = 0x005b4fe8 L"\\\\?\\C:\\My Nested Path\\My Nested Path\\My Nested Path\\My Nested Path\\My Nested Path\\"

Eureka! commenting out this line, the function worked!

```
  //wcscat_s(cumPath, MAX_PATH - 3, __TEXT("\\"));
```

But now there are no nested directories, as was the original requirement.

> cumPath = 0x00644fe8 L"\\?\C:\My Nested PathMy Nested PathMy Nested PathMy Nested PathMy Nested Path"

Comment: this line: `wcscpy_s(cumPath, pathLength, L"\\\\?\\C:\\");` is copying to a pointer that is not pointed to anywhere in particular.  The result is undefined behaviour.

Comment: what you really need is to learn some debugging skills. Start by working out what value is passed to the api function.

Comment: Whoops: What I need are better skills in SO questions. Gave listTotal a value. The callocs for the two variables have been added. However, there is something done with the callocs that may not be legal. The question is updated.

Answer (score 1):

the first problem is that cumPath is not pointed to any allocated memory.

and the wcscpy_s() function expects the destination to be a char array large enough to hold the source bytes

here is a relevant extract from the wcscpy() man page

DESCRIPTION
       The wcscpy() function is the wide-character equivalent of the strcpy(3)
       function.  It copies the  wide-character  string  pointed  to  by  src,
       including  the  terminating  null  wide character (L'\0'), to the array
       pointed to by dest.

```
   The strings may not overlap.

   The  programmer  must  ensure  that  there  is  room   for   at   least
   wcslen(src)+1 wide characters at dest.
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that something is broken in the way the system handles the C compiled nested directory strings.
There is no similar [problem](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/759765/Create-directory-tree-with-Unicode-Files-Path-Cplu) in C++ apparently.

The solution here is to change the current directory with each new directory iteration:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Strsafe.h>


void ErrorExit(LPCTSTR lpszFunction)
{

    DWORD dww = 0;
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;

    dww = GetLastError();
    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dww,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),  (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,0, NULL);

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));


    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR), TEXT("%s failed with error %lu: %s"), lpszFunction, dww, lpMsgBuf);
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, "Error", MB_OK);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
}



int main()
{

wchar_t *currPathW, *cumPathW;
int listTotal = 2;
int errorcode;
int pathLength = MAX_PATH - 3;
int stripLen;
currPathW = (wchar_t *)calloc(pathLength, sizeof(wchar_t));
cumPathW = (wchar_t *)calloc(pathLength, sizeof(wchar_t));
wcscpy_s(cumPathW, pathLength, L"\\\\?\\C:\\");

wcscpy_s(currPathW, MAX_PATH - 3, L"NestedPath");
for (int i = 0; i < listTotal; i++) {

    wcscat_s(cumPathW, pathLength, (wchar_t *) currPathW);
    //OK but doubled backslashes
    wcscat_s(cumPathW, MAX_PATH - 3, L"\\");
    //appear in debugger variable contents
    int errorcode = CreateDirectoryW(cumPathW, NULL);
    if (errorcode == 0) ErrorExit("Failed: ");

}
//wchar_t * currPathWtmp = (wchar_t *)calloc(pathLength, sizeof(wchar_t));
wchar_t * currPathWtmp;
currPathWtmp = cumPathW;
stripLen = wcslen(currPathWtmp)- wcslen(L"NestedPath") - 1;

for (int i = 0; i < listTotal; i++) {

    int errorcode = RemoveDirectoryW(currPathWtmp);
    if (errorcode == 0) ErrorExit("Failed: ");
    currPathWtmp [stripLen] = 0; 

}
//currPathWtmp = NULL;


free(currPathW); 
free(cumPathW); 

}
```

**Edit**: The function failed with "Could Not Find the Path Specified" again on the 256 char barrier, so it looks like jumping a few more coding hoops to get it actually working as advertised.
**Edit2**: Changing PreprocessorDefinitions from _WIN32 to WIN64 (_AMD64 in this case) didn't make any difference.
**Edit3**: Should compile this out of the box now. All working! In actual fact it works for many values of listTotal. Something else going on.

Comment: Can it be that the use of `MAX_PATH` in your code is the problem? It's only [260 characters long](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx). Your own `pathLength` is way larger, and (warning! Random Guess!) probably enough for the next decade.

Comment: That's an idea: Get rid of the wscat by putting the \\ in the listbox string. But no, same problem. +1 for the thought. :)  Wondering if this works if Explorer is terminated.