# Is there any way to open a folder containing long filename in MS Windows perl?

Tags: windows, perl

Perl script to open a folder which contains a longfile name and shows an error "Could not open 'dir' for reading 'Filename too long'"

Comment: filename should not be short only with the same filename it needs to be open. forget to add this point so I added in comments

Comment: Could you pls show us what you have tried? You can edit the question and paste the code. See [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info.

Comment: use `chdir()` to change to a subdirectory, so that the path to the file you want isn't as long.

Comment: Could you name OS you use? https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1002424/how-to-resolve-Filename-too-long-when-readdir-in-p suggest it  is MX Windows specific problem fixed by use of Win32::LongPath

Comment: This question deserves a really good answer from someone who understands the Windows filesystem and its APIs. It's not easy and it's a bit beyond me.

Comment: Ah, I'd asked a similar question before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721807/how-do-i-create-then-use-long-windows-paths-from-perl

Answer (score 4):

## perl: handling long filenames in MS Windows

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1002424/how-to-resolve-Filename-too-long-when-readdir-in-p suggest it  is MS Windows specific problem fixed by use of [Win32::LongPath](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::LongPath) perl module.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers who replied for my question I have used Win32::LongPath and it is working fine.